# Extract elements from matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

How can I extract the elements: [1,2,5,6], [3,4,7,8], [9,10,13,14], [11,12,15,16] ?

```
A = [1,    2,    3,    4;
     5,    6,    7,    8;
     9,    10,   11,  12;
     13,   14,   15,  16;];
```

I'm using octave.

Best regards, Chris.

Comment: What do you mean extract?? What would the output be? Is `[1,2,5,6]` a vector of linear indices that you want to get the corresponding value from `A` for? Or are you asking how to split a matrix in (geometric) quarters?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `mat2cell` at here http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html

Comment: The order [1,2,5,6] should be a vector. I want to build four blocks of matrix A. The first block is [1,2,5,6] and so on...

Comment: thanks @Nishant - the solution: `disp(mat2cell(A,[2 2], [2 2]));`

Comment: @user2372976 `mat2cell(A,[2 2], [2 2])` will give you matrices instead of vector, what do you exactly need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need four matrices then use

```
out = mat2cell(A,[2 2], [2 2]);
```

If you need four vectors with values , then use

```
out = cellfun(@(x)(reshape(x,1,[])),mat2cell(A,[2 2], [2 2]),'UniformOutput',0);
```

output will be

```
out{:,:}

ans =

     1     5     2     6


ans =

     9    13    10    14


ans =

     3     7     4     8


ans =

    11    15    12    16
```

Thanks, to  Joe Serrano ,If you need the value in each of the four vectors in same order use,

```
out = cellfun(@(x)(reshape(x',1,[])),mat2cell(A,[2 2], [2 2]),'UniformOutput',0);
```

output will be

```
out{:,:}

ans =

     1     2     5     6


ans =

     9    10    13    14


ans =

     3     4     7     8


ans =

    11    12    15    16
```

Comment: Might try out = cellfun(@(x) x(:)',mat2cell(A',[2 2], [2 2]),'UniformOutput',0); if order matters